# Vagrant with Ansible for Windows VM

Tags: vagrant, ansible, vagrant-windows

I am trying to run Vagrant with Ansible on my Mac to create and provision a Windows 7 VM. I am able to "vagrant up" when I don't invoke Ansible in the Vagrantfile.

I am using the following playbook.yml

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: run win ping
      win_ping:
```

When I add the ansible code to my Vagrantfile, I get the following error

```
GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
failed: [default] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

To me, this error means it fails to find Python because it is looking for Python as if it is a Linux machine.

Separately, I have run

```
ansible windows -m win_ping
```

where windows is the IP address to the VM brought up by Vagrant so I suspect the issue is not with Ansible but with how Vagrant is invoking Ansible.

Has anyone tried Vagrant + Ansible for a Windows VM? Is there something obvious that I am missing (perhaps an option to pass to Ansible)?

I am using Vagrant version 1.7.2 and Ansible version 1.8.3

Comment: Can you run a `which ansible` and `which python` to check where they are located (especially the latter one). Also, can you run `ansible-playbook windows -m win_ping` and see if that works outside of the vagrant context? Looks like vagrant would be calling `ansible-playbook` internally: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/plugins/provisioners/ansible/provisioner.rb#L62

Comment: Also, does `vagrant up --debug` give you more insight?

Answer (score 2):

With Ansible provisioning a Windows box (either Vagrant, VM or real machine) the configuration is much more important in the first place. Before crafting your playbook, you should have a correct configuration in place.

Having a Windows box managed by Vagrant, your configuration file `group_vars/windows-dev` should contain something like:

```
ansible_user: IEUser
ansible_password: Passw0rd!
ansible_port: 55986 # not 5986, as we would use for non-virtualized environments
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
```

Be sure to insert the correct credentials and choose the right port for `ansible-port`. Working with Vagrant, you can get the correct port from the log-messages produced by Vagrant after a `vagrant up`. In my case this looks like this:

```
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 5985 (guest) => 55985 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 5986 (guest) => 55986 (host) (adapter 1)
```

My [Vagrantfile could be found here](https://github.com/jonashackt/ansible-windows-springboot/blob/master/Vagrantfile), if you´re interested. It uses the *Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 Stable (14.xxx)* image from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms.

Now the [win_ping](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/win_ping_module.html) module should work - assuming that you´ve done all the necessary preparing steps on your Windows box which center around executing the script [ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/scripts/ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1) (more Information could be found in the **Making Windows Ansible ready** chapter in [this blog post](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/01/ansible-windows-spring-boot/)):

```
ansible windows-dev -i hostsfile -m win_ping
```

Only, if this gives you an `SUCCESS` you should proceed with crafting your playbook.

Answer (score 0):

In my Windows provisioning playbook I set this in the header:

gather_facts: no